# Quiero hacer adaptativo un clip de twitch, pero no puedo hacer que la altura se adapte, es fácil con imágenes, pero esto no se por que es distinto

Tags: html5, css3

Asi me funciona con las imágenes, pero video, nope

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <iframe src="https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=WonderfulRacyAlfalfaAliens-mCB4HcBQuMFcTzbU&parent=bysmax.xyz"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" width="100%" max-width="620"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quiero hacer que un clip de twitch o bien un directo sea adaptativo tanto en mobile, como en desktop, funciona bien con imagenes el ancho del 100% y un maximo similar, pero no en el video, no se si tenga que modificarle algo mas

Answer (score 0):

Quiero hacer que un clip de twitch o bien un directo sea adaptativo tanto en mobile, como en desktop, funciona bien con imagenes el ancho del 100% y un maximo similar, pero no en el video, no se si tenga que modificarle algo mas

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).